# Hide Tabwidget from parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to hide one view of parent `fragment` from child `fragment`.

I have one MainActivity which have `container` which loads four `fragments` in first `fragment` there is another container for `Tabwidget` which loads four fragments.Inside fragment I have  `RecyclerView` which loads different item .On click of item there is load of other `fragment`.For this I have to hide  the `Tabwidget` and show whenever press back.

I have searched lots for this scenario but not get success.

Please advise what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I need to hide one view of parent fragment from child fragment.

Create public method in Parent `Fragment`

```
public void hideView() {
   // Handle your hiding code
}
```

To call this method from Child Fragment

```
((YourParentFragmentCLASS) getParentFragment()).hideView(); // getParentFragment() will return parent fragment of current child fragment
```